# How restrict a constraints to a content type?

Tags: 8, entities

I would like to create validation for a several fields on a content type to check if they each have unique values from each other. The part I'm struggling with is how to add the constraint for just my content type, and not all node entities. So far I'm using `hook_entity_type_build()` to add: `$entity_types['node']->addConstraint('UniqueSizes', []);` Is there a way to restrict this to only my content type?

Comment: Do you want this checked before the content is allowed to be submitted?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not directly possibly when adding the constraint.

But you can always check the bundle or existence of certain fields (in some places preferable, if you ever need another node type with those fields and the same logic) within your constraint when it is run.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'm doing the content type validation:

In the hook_entity_type_alter I add the constrain.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_type_alter().
 */
function onlyone_entity_type_alter(array &$entity_types) {
  $entity_types['node']->addConstraint('LockedLanguages');
}
```

And in the Validator I check the content type.

```
/**
 * Validates the LockedLanguages constraint.
 */
class LockedLanguagesConstraintValidator extends ConstraintValidator {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validate($node, Constraint $constraint) {
    // Getting the configured content types.
    if (in_array($node->getType(), ['page', 'article']) {
      // Some code is removed to do this easy to read.
      $this->context->addViolation($constraint->nodeExists, $values);
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add constraints to fields added to a bundle, you can implement [`hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter/8.2.x), which gets the bundle as last parameter.

Keep in mind that, once the changes in [Finalize API for creating, overriding, and altering code-defined bundle fields](https://www.drupal.org/node/2346347) are committed, code implementing `hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter()` would probably need to be changed.